# Memory error in recursive function (Python 2.7.3)

Tags: python

I'm running into a memory error in one of my recursive function.

```
def allPaths(self, adjMat, start, stop, flag=[0], walks=[]):
    walks = walks + [start]
    if start == stop:
        return [walks]
    loc = 0
    flag=flag*len(adjMat)
    output = []
    for value in adjMat[start]:
        if value > 0.0:
            if flag[loc] < 3:
                flag[loc]+=1
                paths = self.allPaths(adjMat, loc, stop, flag, walks)
                for k in paths:
                    output.append(k)
        loc += 1
    return output
```

One example input is fine but I get a memory error with different matrix.

```
>>>print test.allPaths([[0.0, 0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, .15, .05, 0.0, 0.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],0,7)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7], [0, 6, 7]]

>>>print test.allPaths([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
          [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, .05, .15, 0.0, 0.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
          [0.9, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],0,7)
```

The error seems to occur at the line "flag=flag*len(adjMat)". Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but one thing you should probably avoid is to use mutable default arguments like `[0]` and `[]`, as they are only evaluated once on function definition (not every time you call the function as you might expect). See the explanation and discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each recursive call increases the size of the `flag` list by a factor of `len(adjMat)`.

The first call to the function uses a flag list with `len(adjMat)` elements and passes it to the recursive call. There the list will be multiplied by `len(adjMat)`, resulting in `len(adjMat) * len(adjMat)` elements. With a few recursive calls this can quickly get out of hand and you probably run out of memory to store this excessively large `flag` list.